# creating a link_to for custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a custom route (if I am doing that correctly, this is the first time I have done this) that looks like this:

```
map.connect 'purchases/type/:type', :controller => 'purchases', :action => 'index'
```

so I want to create a link_to that would use that url /purchases/type/(somenumber)

or I am completely open for a better way to do it.

**Edit:**

I am trying to use a category (type) to filter on the index.  So if I click the link that would be /purchases/type/1 that would show all the items from type 1.  I dont want this in the show, and I could do it with /purchases/?type=1, but im trying to make the urls look better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Untested but I believe this is what you want...

```
map.purchase_type 'purchases/type/:type', :controller => 'purchases', :action => 'index'
```

Then

```
link_to 'foo', purchase_type_path(:type => 'your_type')
```

Good luck.

Comment: this should work, but you will need to add _path or _url to the end.  purchase_type_path(...)

Answer (score 1):

Based on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails-2.1/rails-routes.htm (section "named routes"), I'd try the following:

```
map.purchases_for_type 'purchases/type/:type', :controller => 'purchases', :action => 'index'
```

And I assume you'd then call it with `link_to 'link text', purchases_for_type(@type_param)`

---

For reference, I'll include the Rails3 way to do it:

```
match '/purchases/type/:type' => 'purchases#index', :as => "purchases_for_type", :via => "get"
```

Or better yet (RESTful):

```
match '/type/:type/purchases' => 'purchases#index', :as => "purchases_for_type", :via => "get"
```

You'd then call it with `link_to 'link text', purchases_for_type(@type_param)`

Comment: I am getting a undefined method `purchases_for_type', so I guess im doing something wrong.  I am putting the map.purchases... in the routes.rb and the link_to in my view.  The purchases_for_type(<this is a number that is the id of the type>).  Does that see correct?

Comment: My rails2 is rusty... Maybe try something like Cory suggests: `link_to 'link text', purchases_for_type(:type => @type_param)`